# PHP mysqli - updating value of enum field results in empty string, but same query works when run in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysqli, enums

The query:

```
UPDATE caption_queue SET status = 'Conversion Completed' WHERE tpi_id = '3130'
```

As stated in the title, when I run this in PHP, the value is set to an empty string. However, when the exact same query is run directly in MySQL, it works correctly.

On top of that, I'm only getting this behavior on a single enum value: 'Conversion Completed'. When updating with other values (most of which also contain spaces), there is no problem.

Actual PHP code for those interested:

```
$sql = "UPDATE caption_queue SET status = 'Conversion Completed' WHERE tpi_id = '$tpi_id'";
$val = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
//$link comes from somewhere else, but we use it extensively throughout our website
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `caption_queue` (
`tpi_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pid` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`conversion_began` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`yt_caption_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`yt_video_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('Pending Conversion','Converting','Conversion Completed','Pending Upload','Video Processing','Video Processed','Uploading Transcription','Caption Syncing','Caption Synced','Caption Downloading','Caption Ready') DEFAULT 'Pending Conversion'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What's the return value when you run the query?

Comment: How are you running that statement on PHP? Show us the snippet.

Comment: It returns true, indicating success. Also, mysqli_error() returns nothing.

Comment: show the table definition, particularly the enum field definition.

Comment: I added relevant PHP and the table definition to my question

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MySQLI and your database has enums you need to find the place of your value in order to update your database because it does not accept new strings!

here is an example of the column of my database configuration!

```
status  enum('active', 'inactive', 'banned')
```

if you want to update these values convert the values into numbers for example active = 1, inactive = 2, banned = 3

from PHP we are able to do the following

```
$query = 'UPDATE '.$this->table.' SET status = :status' 
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
if($this->status == 'active') 
    {
      $finalStatus = 1;
    }

    if($this->status == 'inactive') 
    {
      $finalStatus = 2;
    }

    if($this->status == 'banned') 
    {
      $finalStatus = 3;
    }
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $finalStatus);
$stmt->execute();
```

and this will save your day!

this code was used as an example to provide a full solution to this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I think you'll find it should work if you put the column called status in back ticks.

```
$query="UPDATE caption_queue SET `status` = 'Conversion Completed' WHERE tpi_id = '3130'";
```

Comment: Nope. That was something I had already tried (just did again to be sure though). Like I said, the weird thing is it only fails for 'Conversion Completed', and only when executed through mysqli.

Comment: I guess it's not working for me either but I cannot change the database structure since its a big database!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. By using strict mode:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

I'm able to update the field with no issues. Seems like some kind of issue with mysqli.